# how to search for a node in binary tree?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

```
node * search(node *root,int k) {
    if(root == NULL)
      return NULL;
    if(root->data == k)
      return root;
    else {
      search(root->left,k);
      search(root->right,k);
   }
    return NULL;
}
```

I dont know why this function is not working? Please Help.

Comment: define 'not working'

Comment: Although its somewhat obvious, I would recommend adding a language tag to this (might get better responses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the result of the recursive calls if the node is found.

```
node * search(node *root,int k) {
    if(root == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    } else if (root->data == k) {
      return root;
    } else {
      node* x = search(root->left,k);
      if (x)
        return x;         //if we find in left subtree, return result
      return search(root->right,k);
    }
}
```